# Complex Number to a power

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I asked this question yesterday, but the answers did not actually answer what I wanted to know since I asked the question in the wrong way.

I have $e^{i\frac{2014\pi}{12}}$. I know  Euler's formula, but I don't know how to take the sine or cosine of such an angle; that is, I do not know how to simplify this so I can convert to standard form. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Euler's formula, if you don't know it, spend a week getting to know it.

Comment: That is not a useful comment. Even if I have $\cos(\frac{2014\pi}{12}) + i\sin(\frac{2014 \pi}{12}))$, my question still stands

Comment: $e^i\theta=\cos \theta + i\sin \theta$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant My question still stands. How do I know what $\cos(2014\pi)$ is? or $\cos(321\pi)$? etc

Comment: @Telon You have it in standard form $a+bi$, what other form do you want exactly?

Comment: (Couldn't resist) Euler's formula says  (imagin)ary exponenti(ation)number can give a real number.  Combined it says, imagination can lead to real results.

Comment: Oh I see, subtract multiples of $2\pi$ till the angle is between $0$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Explain how I find out what $e^{i \frac{2014 \pi}{12}}$ is in the most simplified standard form. That is my question.

Comment: @Telon You already now the answer, just find it in your mind (or on your mechanical calculator if you prefer). Do you see this is just the equation for a circle in the complex plane!

Comment: $2014\pi/12=1007\pi/6$.  Now you can subtract 84 $2\pi$'s and get something you recognize.

Comment: $2014\pi/12 - 84 \cdot 2\pi=-\pi/6$.  And you know what $\sin(-\pi/6)$ and $\cos(-\pi/6)$ are.

Comment: I don't understand your logic.

Comment: Keep in mind $\cos(x+n\cdot 2\pi)=\cos(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.  Same for $\sin$.

Comment: Notice that you would have gotten much better answers, more quickly, if you had mentioned in the question "I know to use Euler's formula, but I don't know how to take the sine or cosine of [this angle]." Your question isn't about complex numbers at all, you need to work on trigonometry.

Answer (score 4):

Use Euler's formula, $e^{ix}=\cos x + i \sin x$, taking $x=\frac{2014\pi}{12}$. This means that $$e^{i\frac{2014\pi}{12}}=\cos(\frac{2014\pi}{12})+i\sin(\frac{2014\pi}{12})$$

Now, note that cos and sin are periodic with period $2\pi$. This means $\cos(x)=\cos(x+2n\pi)$, where n is an integer. Taking $n=-83$ gives $$\cos(\frac{2014\pi}{12})=\cos\left(\frac{2014\pi}{12}-(83)(2\pi)\right)$$
$$=\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

The same logic with sin gives $$\sin\left(\frac{2014\pi}{12}\right)=\sin(\frac{11\pi}{6})=-\frac{1}{2}$$

So the answer is
$$e^{i\frac{2014\pi}{12}}=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}-\frac{i}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$2014=167 \times 12 + 10$

$ \dfrac{2014}{12} \pi= 167 \pi+ \dfrac{5}{6} \pi=83 \times (2\pi)+\dfrac {11}{6} \pi$

$e^{i\frac{2014}{12}}=e^{83 \times (2\pi)+\frac {11}{6} \pi}=e^{\frac {11}{6} \pi}$

Answer (score 1):

You have $1007\equiv -1\mod12$, hence $\dfrac{1007\pi}6\equiv -\dfrac\pi6\mod 2\pi$. Since $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i2\pi}=1$, we have:
$$\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\tfrac{1007\pi}6}=\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\tfrac{\pi}6}=\frac{\sqrt 3}2-\frac12\mathrm i$$